# Including the current node in the find scope

Tags: javascript, jquery, find, selector

Consider the following snippet as an example:

```
<div class="bar foo">
</div>

<div class="bar">
    <div class="foo"></div>
</div>
```

Given `var $set=$('.bar');` I need to select both nodes with `foo` class. What is the proper way to achieve this. Considering `addBack()` requires a selector and here we need to use the `$set` jQuery object and `$set.find('.foo')` does not select the first node.

Comment: `$('.bar')` itself have both nodes. because it's a parent class.so what's basically your problem?

Answer (score 0):

use this :

```
var $set =  $(".bar").filters(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    if($this.is(".foo") || $this.find(" > .foo").length !== 0){
        return true;
    } else{
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your try, I hope there is a far shorter solution. And please consider the snippet is provided to explain the general problem only.

Comment: @PHPst my short solution is $(".bar.foo, .bar:has(.foo)") and i test work true. whith this you can select both '.bar'.

Comment: @MohmmadEbrahimiAval Dear Mohammad you have access only to `$set` variable and as mentioned the snippet is only for explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way of going about it:

```js
var set = $('.bar');
var foos = [];

for (var i = 0; i < set.length; i++) {
  if ($(set[i]).hasClass('foo')) {
    foos.push(set[i]);
  }
}

if (set.find('.foo').length !== 0) {
  foos.push(set.find('.foo')[0]);
}

console.log(foos);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="bar foo"></div>
<div class="bar">
  <div class="foo"></div>
</div>
```

The `for` loop checks all elements picked up with jQuery's `$('.bar')`, and checks if they also have the `foo` class. If so, it appends them to the array. The `if` checks if any of the elements picked up in `set` have any **children** that have the `foo` class, and also adds them.

This creates an array that contains both of the DIVs with the `foo` class, while excluding the one with just `bar`.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

test this :

```
 var $newSet = $set.filter(".foo").add($set.has(".foo"));
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use the [addBack()](http://api.jquery.com/addback/) function

```js
var $set=$('.bar');
console.log($set.find(".foo").addBack(".foo"));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="bar foo">
</div>

<div class="bar">
    <div class="foo"></div>
</div>
```